# How to dynamically set AppID key in angular module in ngx-agora

Tags: angular, video-streaming, webrtc, agora.io

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-agora for video calling in angular 8.
as per the documentation, I need to provide APPID static as below

```
const agoraConfig: AgoraConfig = {
  AppID: '1239021930912039-02193',
};

 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxAgoraModule.forRoot(agoraConfig)
  ],
```

but I want to set AppId value from API response based on the environment . How Can I set it using APP_INITIALIZER of angular ? or is there any other way I can set it?

Comment: Are you currently using environment files?

Comment: no.I like to set using API

Comment: @ZalaNilesh can you please share with me any demo of how you have integrated I also want to do the same but not getting any proper blogs for angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with providers doesn't work when using AOT as NgxAgoraModule uses 'useValue' in forRoot.

But you can set APPID later in the process like this:

```ts
export const agoraConfig: AgoraConfig = {
   AppID: null //setting null here
};

@NgModule({
...
imports: [
    ...
    NgxAgoraModule.forRoot(agoraConfig),
    ....
],
...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and then at the place you're creating a agora client (your component)

```ts
// false at the end disabled auto initializing
this.client = this.ngxAgoraService.createClient({mode: 'rtc', codec: 'h264'}, false);
this.client.init('your-agora-APPID');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `APP_INITIALIZER` like so:

1. Create a service to retrieve configuration from API, let's call it `AppConfigService`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  private appConfig;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  loadAppConfig() {
    return this.http.get('http://url-to-config-from-environment.ts')
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        this.appConfig = data;
      });
  }

  getConfig() {
    return this.appConfig;
  }
}
```

^ in this service you need to implement the actual code to retrieve configuration based on the environment. [Here's is an example](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/separating-production-and-development-http-urls-using-environment-ts-file-in-angular-4c2dd0c5a8b0) of that.

2. Inject the service in AppModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFn,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService]
    }
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. Implement the `appInitializerFn` factory function in `AppModule`:

```js
...
const appInitializerFn = (appConfig: AppConfigService) => {
  return () => {
    return appConfig.loadAppConfig();
  };
};

@NgModule({
```

You can [refer to this article](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/) for more details.

Comment: but how to set APPID value in agoraConfig for NgxAgoraModule.forRoot(agoraConfig)